# What SMDs are these?

Tags: resistors, surface-mount

Just a quick question: Does anyone know what SMD are these?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? You have tagged the question as resistor, so you probably know that these are resistors. They have their values printed on, so that can't be the question either. You seem to physically have them, so the size isn't the question too. So what is it that you want to know?

Comment: I wonder if one could tell which size it is based on the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, these are resistors, and their value is

\$1874: \quad 187\cdot10^4\Omega=1.870M\Omega\$

\$3403: \quad 340\cdot10^3\Omega=340k\Omega\$

\$2003: \quad 200\cdot10^3\Omega=200k\Omega\$

Because the mantissa consists of three digits, the resistors have a precision of 1%. For 5% or worse, the mantissa has only two digits.

Comment: What is your source for this version of the code? The multiplier on a 3-digit code applies the DP after the first two digits, so that 203 = 20kilohms. Same applies (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#SMT_resistors ) for 4-digit codes, making 2003 200 kilohms, not 2 kilohms.

Comment: Absolutely true, no idea what I wrote there. I've corrected it.

Comment: Downvote removed after correction.